# SSIS Script Task check folder for any XML files

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task

I'm using SQL Server 2014 \ SSIS.

I have the below code within a Script Task to check if a folder contains any XML files:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        string folder = Dts.Variables["$Project::XMLFilePath"].Value.ToString();     

        Dts.Variables["User::fileExists"].Value = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.xml").Any();


        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

However, I keep receiving the error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   could be found

Why does it not like the .Any?  I'm using the `System.IO` namespace.

Comment: Try following : Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.xml").Any()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the LINQ namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```